# Help pertaining to cURL on Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

Good day everyone. I'm currently programming in Moodle. Since I haven't got any answers yet in their forums I will have to ask it here because I really need help badly. How can my cURL bypass Moodle login page?

```
    $ckfile = tempnam("/tmp","CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init(http://127.0.0.1/login/index.php);

    $data = array('username' => 'admin', 'password' => 'Admin_123');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $url = "http://127.0.0.1/mod/quiz/report.php?q=4&mode=analysis";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $output;

    curl_close($ch);
```

Given this code, I have successfully logged in as admin but the problem is that I'm still stuck in the login page instead of proceeding to the url (http://127.0.0.1/mod/quiz/report.php?q=4&mode=analysis) which is supposed to be my target. How am I suppose to bypass the login page? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you ever execute the connection to the login page?

Comment: In a way I did because on the upper left I saw I successfully logged in but I remain stuck in the login page.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use moodle with PHP, you should not use cURL to work on the pages, but instead use the [Moodle API](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services). If for any reason you still want to use the webpages, you should at least use the Moodle API to [authenticate](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/External_services_security). This gives you a session-token, with which you may access subsequent pages.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yeah I been thinking about using Moodle API but really I have little time remaining, is there a fast way to learn Moodle API?

Comment: Never used it, but it looks pretty standard: http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=151921